# Is UserDefaults deprecated in Xcode 10, Swift 4.2?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, xcode10, swift4.2

I am creating an app that requires to have a `UserDefaultManager`. But unfortunately it shows an error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'UserDefaults'

I tried to solve it by declaring a variable like:

```
let UserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

but it is still not working for me. Attached below are my codes for your references. Hope you can help me. By the way I am using xcode 10.

```
struct UserDefaultsManager {
    private static let isLoggedInKey = "com.example.key.isLoggedIn"

    //  let UserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    static func login() {
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: isLoggedInKey)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

    static func logout() {
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(false, forKey: isLoggedInKey)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

    static func isLoggedIn() -> Bool {
        return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: isLoggedInKey)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you `import Foundation`?

Comment: And don't use `synchronize`. Read its documentation.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, i used `import Foundation`

Comment: Your code compiles just fine for me in a Swift 4.2 playground with Xcode 10.1.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but do not use `setValue(_:forKey:)`. Use `setBool(_:forKey:)`.

Comment: can you add your full class code

Comment: I don't think it's Deprecated. As far as I know, if it's something Deprecated Xcode still support the Syntax it's just show us `Warning` not an `Error`. You can refer the some of very good tutorial on `UserDefaults' in the link. 

https://medium.com/@nimjea/userdefaults-in-swift-4-d1a278a0ec79

Hope this works.

Comment: As far as I can tell there's nothing wrong with your code... Did you try to clean build folder and rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't deprecated. This is my code: 
save data

```
    let user = UserDefaults.standard
    user.set(userJson.email, forKey: "email")
    user.set(userJson.id, forKey: "id")
    user.set(userJson.username, forKey: "user")
```

and get data

```
    let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    getEmailToCheck = userDefault.string(forKey: "email") ?? ""
    user_id = userDefault.string(forKey: "id") ?? ""
```

and you don't need to import Foundation directly in your swift file. Hope this helps you.

Comment: This does not solve whatever issue the OP is having.

Comment: so as for me it causes by wrong declaration:
let UserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

Comment: But that line is commented out. The code in the question works just fine as-is.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I run these code and get the same result. May be need more details from the OP.

Comment: *“you don't need to import Foundation”* – that is not true, or at least misleading. (It might work for you if you import other frameworks or bridging header files which indirectly import the Foundation framework.)

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry about that. My case is bridging header files which indirectly import.

Comment: Can someone explain why this answer is getting up voted? No offense to the poster but this answer doesn't solve anything.